# Is it possible to change the terminal colour based on Nightshift (sunset/-rise)

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos

I want to have a conditional terminal color based on the Nightshift (sunrise/-set).

I am using macOS BigSur 11.2.3 and the default terminal with zsh.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about your specific terminal emulator, but in `xterm` (whose API many terminal emulators have copied), you can do:

```
printf '\e]11;%s\a' colorname
```

to set the background colour. Where *colorname* can be any colour specification as supported by  the `XParseColor()` X library function.

Then you could have `zsh` send escape sequences with a colour corresponding to the position of the sun in the sky before each prompt with something like:

```
MY_LONGITUDE=$(curl -s 'http://ip-api.com/line?fields=lon')

# sanitise to avoid command injection vulnerability
[[ $MY_LONGITUDE = (-|)<0-180>(.<->|) ]] || MY_LONGITUDE=0

zmodload zsh/datetime
settermbg() {
  local sun_time distance_to_noon hue value chroma
  ((         sun_time = (${1-EPOCHSECONDS} + MY_LONGITUDE * 86400 / 360) % 86400 ))
  (( distance_to_noon = (sun_time - 43200. ) / 43200 )) # between -1 and 1

  ((              hue = (distance_to_noon + 1) * 180 ))
  ((            value = 100 - distance_to_noon ** 2 * 50 ))
  ((           chroma = distance_to_noon ** 2 * 60 ))

  printf '\e]11;TekHVC:%5g/%5g/%5g\a' $hue $value $chroma
}

precmd_functions+=(settermbg)
```

Here using the `TekHVC:hue/value/chroma` colour specification with values computed based on the distance to noon (sun time), with the brightest and whitest background when the sun is highest in the sky.

Here, your longitude (used to determine when the sun is highest in the sky) is determined based on your IP address using an online service provided by `ip-api.com`. It may not always  give you the correct value. You may want to hardcode it instead if you're not travelling.